# Obtain conditional distribution of a 3 way table

Tags: r

I have a table

```
table(A,B,C)
```

how can I obtain/extract the distribution of C for given values of A=a and B=b?

Comment: Can you give me more information, more details ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a data frame:

```
dat <- data.frame(A = c(rep("a1", 5), rep("a2", 5)),
                  B = c(rep("b1", 5), rep("b2", 5)),
                  C = c(rep("c1", 5), rep("c2", 5)))
```

Here's your three-way table:

```
with(dat, table(A, B, C))
```

Here's the distribution of `C` (rows) when `A` and `B` take on specified values:

```
with(dat, table(C, A == "a1" & B == "b1"))
```